# Tag List View with longer tags not fully displayed in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using [TagListView](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView), when tags with lengthly content is added that is not fully displayed. Is there any possible solution for this issue?.[image]

Comment: Have you got any solution for the above?

Comment: @martinsaha. I think they have fixed issue in swift 4 release

Comment: Thanks for the response will check right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the latest version (1.3)

https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView/issues/149